# Difference between environment in Dockerfile RUN and interactive shell on a running container?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, oracle11g, docker

I'm starting with a [Docker image that has OracleXE installed on it](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/wnameless/oracle-xe-11g/dockerfile/).  This image has a running instance, with everything configured.
I can fire up that image, and, either from an interactive shell container, or by ssh'ing into the container, I can easily execute `sqlplus`.

To create a container with my desire additions, such as a new oracle user and tablespaces, I can go into the running container and execute the necessary `sqlplus`, and then `docker commit` a new image with my new state.  However, I would like to capture these new changes in a `Dockerfile`.

BUT . .. when my Dockerfile tries to execute the same commands as referenced above, the `PATH` doesn't have the `ORACLE_HOME` on it; while it clearly does when I go into the container with `SSH` or interactive shell.

Note, the original Dockerfile, linked to above, uses the following to set the PATH.

```
RUN echo 'export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo 'export ORACLE_SID=XE' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

What's the difference between the environment when the RUN command executes and when I go into the container via the interactive shell or SSH?  Note, this all starts with a ubuntu 14.04 image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [Bash manual entry on startup files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

When you run interactively, the shell executes its rcfiles:

> **When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell**, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

When your Dockerfile is building, it's running a non-interactive shell:

> **When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example**, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi`
> ```

You *could* set `BASH_ENV` to make things run. Or use `RUN bash --login <command>` or `RUN . /etc/bash.bashrc && <command>` on every line of your Dockerfile. That's pretty gross, though.

I would use the `ENV` dockerfile command to set those variables. I'm not sure why the original set them up the way it does.

Comment: Yeah, so the ENV seems like the right idea.  The docs say that they will even be part of the environment of a running container running from the docker image.  However, whatever that might mean, it doesn't seem to cover the SSH in to the container environment. . .

Comment: Yes, that's true. When you use `docker run` or `docker exec` you'll get the environment, but not if you run an sshd inside the container and SSH there. I always use exec (`docker exec -it my_container bash`) to explore a running container.

Comment: It's just when docker controls the entry.   That makes sense.